Python not recognized in VS Code
I want to use VS Code to make a simple in Python. But whenever I use VS Code this error  occurs:
'python' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

I tried using PyCharm to see if it works and it just did a whole lot of other things. But when I used IDLE, I thought it won't work because I was also not able to find the Python file in C:\Program Files, but it did work.

You have to install Python Extended in Vscode and make sure you also install Python on your device.

Make sure you've visited the download page for Python and install it using your native launcher (or the terminal if you so choose).
Next, open the Extensions tab in Visual Studio Code by clicking the stack of four boxes on your toolbar or with Ctrl+Shift+X, then search for Python and install the verified result developed by Microsoft: direct link.
There should be no reason for Visual Studio Code to behave like Python is not installed if these steps were followed before this post.
